# Filter a list by using another list in PowerQuery M code

Tags: excel, vba, powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a list of column names. I want to filter the list, by using the items in another list. I want to return all column names that **Contains** any of the items in the myFilter List.
If the Filter is text item I can make the filter, but I could not manage to go through each item and return a list.

```
ColumnNames= {"E ID", "W ID", "P Chemical", "XIC","YFE","ZIC"}
myFilter = {"W ID","IC"}
```

The result should be:

```
Result = {"W ID","P Chemical", "XIC", "ZIC"}
```

As IC is contained in Chemical, XIC and ZIC, and W ID is a full match.

I imagine it should be something like this:

```
List.Select(ColumnNames, each Text.Contains(_, each myFilter{_}))
```

Because it works with this

```
List.Select(ColumnNames,each Text.Contains(_,"W ID"))
```

But I cannot get the right code, and I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like this.

[image]

```
let
    columnNames= {"E ID", "W ID", "P Chemical", "XIC","YFE","ZIC"},
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(columnNames, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Converted to Table",{{"Column1", "columnNames"}}),
    myFilter = {"W ID","IC"},
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "filter", each myFilter),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "filter"),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Custom", "match", each if Text.Contains([columnNames], [filter], Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) then true else false),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom1", each [match] = true)[columnNames]
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out

```
List.Select(ColumnNames, each List.Contains(myFilter , _))
```

Comment: the list items do not match exactly, but the text in myFilter needs to be matched by Text.Contains or something similar.

Comment: I updated the question with the desired output to make it more clear. I need to match any part of the tex in the filter, with the column names.

Answer (score 2):

You can use set functions like intersect.

```
= List.Intersect({ColumnNames, myFilter})



let
   ColumnNames= {"E ID", "W ID", "P Chemical", "XIC","YFE","ZIC"},
    myFilter = {"W ID","IC"},
    result = List.Intersect({ColumnNames, myFilter})
in
    result
```

[image]

Comment: I updated the question with the desired output to make it more clear. I need to match any part of the tex in the filter, with the column names.

Answer (score 2):

For fun

```
let ColumnNames= {"E ID", "W ID", "P Chemical", "XIC","YFE","ZIC"},
myFilter = {"W ID","IC"},
Part1=List.Transform(ColumnNames, each let q=_ in try Table.SelectRows (Table.FromList(myFilter), each Text.Contains(q,[Column1], Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)){0}[Column1] otherwise null),
Part2= List.RemoveNulls(List.Transform(List.Positions(ColumnNames),each if Part1{_}=null then null else ColumnNames{_}))
in Part2
```